# How to place two 3d models in different div? Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

The page has a **divs** with classes **"skin"**, **"skin2"**, **"skin3"**...
And for each class you need to place your 3d model.

I'm trying to do this, but all the 3d models, are tied to the first model.

*I want to do this using the example of this site [minecraft-skins](https://ru.namemc.com/minecraft-skins/profile/Guillks.2)*

[Image code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ergu.png)

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 50);
camera.position.z = 20;
camera.position.y = 1.5;
camera.position.x = 0;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
renderer.setSize(200, 300);
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight();
scene.add(light);
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load('/Стив.gltf', function (gltf) {
    let obj = gltf;
    document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0].insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0].firstChild);
    scene.add(obj.scene);
    obj.scene.scale.set(4.8, 1.5, 4.9);
    obj.scene.rotation.y += 3.6;
    obj.scene.rotation.x += 0.06;
});

loader.load('/Стив1.gltf', function (gltf2) {
    let obj = gltf2;
    document.getElementsByClassName('skin1')[0].insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.getElementsByClassName('skin1')[0].firstChild);
    scene.add(obj.scene);
    obj.scene.scale.set(4.8, 1.5, 4.9);
    obj.scene.rotation.y += 3.6;
    obj.scene.rotation.x += 0.06;
});

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm>
<head>
    <title>Skins</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
    <div class="skin">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="skin1">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="./script_01.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates one renderer.  On the first call to `.insertBefore()`, that renderer puts its context in the `skin` `div`.  On the second call to `.insertBefore()`, that context is moved out of the `skin` `div` and into the `skin1` `div`; at that point, there's no rendering being done inside of `skin`.

To achieve what you want, it's best to create a renderer that covers the whole window.  Then you can use the renderer's `.setScissor()` method to render inside the limits of each `div`.  Three.js provides [an example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html) of this.

Comment: Yes, I understood this project. Didn't find the answer

Comment: I still haven't figured out where to add ".setScissor()"

Comment: You'll need to create a `Scene` for each `div`; then you'll have a `.render()` call related to each scene, and before each `.render()` call, you'll call `.setScissor()` for the bounds of the `div` that that scene should be drawn into.